# Change time format in php

Tags: php, datetime

Please help in converting 1st date format into 2nd date format.

This is just example:

**2016-08-18 22:09:53**

to

**2016-08-18T09:20:00+08:00**

I am using

```
$the_date = strtotime("016-08-18 22:09:53");
echo(date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date) . "<br />");
```

**OUTPUT**

Asia/calcutta

**2016-18-08IST22:09:53230**

but this time format is still not similar to **2016-08-18T09:20:00+08:00**

Comment: echo(date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP",$the_date) . "<br />");

Comment: Use format `c` while formating with `date()` function, which will return `ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)`; example `2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00`. And change timezone if you wish to get `+08:00` offset.

Comment: @sanjeev I am trying to understand, which is the correlation between the time of the first date and the time of the second date you provided in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$the_date = strtotime("016-08-18 22:09:53");
echo date(DATE_ATOM, $the_date);
```

Comment: is DATE_ATOM php 7 feature?

Comment: (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

Answer (score 0):

use this format "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"

Comment: echo date(DATE_ATOM, $the_date);  this is easy to remember

Comment: @AchyutKrDeka, can you please help me, Friday, September 23, 2016 09:25 [IST] can we create mentioned  date into DATE_ATOM

Comment: you can use  date('r',strtotime('now')); or you can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php for more info

Comment: i have this value in DB, now i want it's DATE_ATOM format

Comment: @AchyutKrDeka can you please help me, Friday, September 23, 2016 09:25 [IST] can we create mentioned date into DATE_ATOM. this value is saved in DB